# Sending POST request to the server inside docker

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a webserver application on django running inside docker container alongside celery. 
Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: '2'
services:
  app:
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - /etc/myapp:/etc/myapp
      - /opt/myapp/static:/myapp/collected_static
      - /opt/myapp/media:/myapp/media
      - /opt/myapp/datasets:/myapp/datasets
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    command: ./deploy/docker_entry.sh
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
    tty: true
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myapp
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myapp
      POSTGRES_DB: myapp
    volumes_from:
      - data
    ports:
      - "5432"
  data:
    image: busybox:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgres
    command: "true"
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    hostname: redis
  worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ./deploy/run_celery.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - .:/app
      - /etc/myapp:/etc/myapp
      - /opt/myapp/media:/myapp/media
    links:
      - db
      - redis
```

My Dockerfile:
        FROM python:3.6

```
    RUN pip3 install -U pip setuptools
    RUN pip3 install uwsgi

    ADD . /myapp

    ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE app.settings

    # Install R for rpy2
    RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y r-base

    RUN pip3 install -r /pandora/requirements.txt

    EXPOSE 8080
    EXPOSE 8000
    EXPOSE 80

    WORKDIR /myapp
```

The problem is, that Im not able to send POST request from my frontend on ReactJS. Consider the following function:

```
            $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/myapp/upload_user_sample/',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',                    
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    })
```

When you send request, server is not able to see it in views.py. 
If you change 'POST' to 'GET' you are able to get this request in views.py, but you're not able to get the data. How could I fix it?
views.py:

```
   @login_required
   def upload_user_sample(request):
        log.debug("{}".format(request.method))
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            sample = UserSample()
            sample.user = user
```

Comment: did you solve it eventually? I'm having a similar problem.